# Size of the orbits for $3$-coloring of vertices of a tetrahedron.

Tags: abstract-algebra, combinatorics, group-theory, group-actions, coloring

For the case of coloring the four vertices of a tetrahedron, given by the set $\{1,2,3,4\},$ by $n=2$ colors; have $2^4= 16$ colorings.

The symmetries for rotation, of tetrahedron ($A_4$), are given by the following:

- Identity rotation: $e,$
- Rotations about any vertex, in both clockwise and counter-clockwise directions:
  $$(234), (432), (123), (312), (134), (413), (124), (412),$$
- Rotations about the midpoints of the opposite edges:
  $$(12)(34), (13)(24), (14)(23).$$

The set $X_{n=2}$ is divided into five equivalence classes (orbits) based on the mappings induced by action of group elements on the set $X_{n=2}.$

The orbits are of size: $1,4,6,4,1.$

Want to know if the number of colors are changed to $n=3,$ then what are the sizes of orbits, without making detailed tables for the same.

*Kindly vet:*

Let, the $n=3$ colors are denoted by $a,b,c$ respectively.
The orbits of size $1$ have the elements as :
$aaaa, bbbb, cccc.$

The left elements of the set $X_{n=3}$ are $3^4-3= 78.$

The elements of the set: $X_{n=3}$ of the form $2a-2b, 2a-2c, 2b-2c,$ are given by first choosing two colors, out of three. Next filling two places (out of $4$), from the first chosen one.
This gives: $3C2\cdot 4C2\cdot 2= 36.$
Each of these elements , $x,$ has the Stabilizer $|\text{Stab}(x)|=2.$

The rest of the elements are : $78-36= 42.$

These have two orbits of the form:
a) $1a-3b, 1a-3c, 1b-3c :$
The number of such elements are:
$4C3\cdot 3= 12.$

b) $3a-1b, 3a-1c, 3b-1c :$
The number of such elements are:
$12.$

Still $42-24= 18$ elements are left?

***Edit #1:***

The case of $2a-2b, 2a-2c, 2b-2c,$ gets only $18$ colorings. Say, first choose a particular color out of $3,$ then select two places out of $4$ to fill in by that color. This gives: $3.4C2= 3.6= 18$ ways, but the second color can be any of the two left. This means need be multiplied by $2C1=2$ ways. Then, get $36$ rather than $18$ ways, or colorings. Say, if the first color (first to fill in two places) chosen is $a,$ then : $aaxx, axxa, axax, xxaa, xaax, xaxa.$ And, there are three ways to choose the first color. So, $18$ ways. Then, there are two ways to choose the second color. But, there is symmetry in : $aaxx, axxa, axax, xxaa, xaax, xaxa,$ as only two colors are involved. Hence, a total of $18$ distinct colorings.

Comment: @Arkady In case of two colors, have $|X_{n=2}|=16.$ I just extended the problem. But, seems there are more orbits for the case of $n=3,$ that cannot see.

Comment: Feel there is so much hidden in this seemingly simple problem, as no response till now.

Comment: You've double counted the colorings of the form $aabb$. This then leaves $36$ and not $18$ colorings unaccounted for, which are of the form $aabc$. There's $3$ different types of those, one for each color that's doubled up. No nontrivial element of the group fixes this coloring, so the $3$ orbits are of size $12$.

Comment: @JoshB. Thanks, I got confused enough to consider some fundamental error. Found some material in the book by: Origami, edn. 3, by Thomas Hull; as at: https://books.google.co.in/books?id=vfrRBQAAQBAJ&pg=PA156&dq=orbits+symmetries+of+tetrahedron+rotations&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&source=gb_mobile_search&ovdme=1&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiW-M_voZr7AhU0ELcAHQ-jDGQQ6AF6BAgNEAM#v=onepage&q=orbits%20symmetries%20of%20tetrahedron%20rotations&f=false. Can you please point out what is the 'seed edge' on page #156; 'orbitals' on page #157. Want to know if that is the standard approach to list orbits.

Comment: @JoshB. Kindly vet the edit as why the $2-2$ case (two colors, each filling in two vertices) has the number of colorings as $18,$ rather than $36.$